# QMdiArea: on sub window changed

Tags: c++, qt

I want to make a label changing text when the user switch sub window on QMdiArea. So i've already done the label change:

```
*m_selection = m_zoneCentrale->activeSubWindow()->windowTitle();
m_label->setText(*m_selection);
```

And that works well but I don't know how to trigger this, the question is so how can I trigger this on sub window change in a QMdiArea?

Thank in advance for responses.

Answer (score 0):

Solved, I didn't see the subWindowActivated signal of QMdiArea.